# FormFlow DefineAsyncDelegate being called multiple times

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

When defining dynamic buttons in FormFlow seems the Define function is being called multiple times (once after each field is asked).

The define function is executing heavy commands which we would like to avoid when unecessary. Those commands are used to calculate the dynamic buttons values. 
Is there a way to avoid executing the define function multiple times? For instance only after specific fields were completed by the user?
Is there a way to know when specific fields are completed?

```
public static IForm<BoardForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<BoardForm>()
            .Field(new FieldReflector<BoardForm>(nameof(ExistingAccountName))
                .SetType(null)
                .SetActive(IsExistingClusterChosen)
//This is a heavy function which is called multiple times
                .SetDefine(DefineExistingAccountName))
.Build();
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, and extensive debugging and web search didn't help me in finding the root cause of the multiple executions. But I can suggest you implementing a simple workaround:

```
private IForm<BoardForm> BuildOrderForm()
{
    var isSetDefineExecuted = false;

    return new FormBuilder<BoardForm>()
        .Field(new FieldReflector<BoardForm>(nameof(ExistingAccountName))
        .SetType(null)
        .SetActive(IsExistingClusterChosen)
            .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
            {
                if (isSetDefineExecuted)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                isSetDefineExecuted = true;

                // Your code
            }))
        .Build();
}
```

isSetDefineExecuted flag prevents any additional execution after the first one. It returns true to indicate "successful" execution, as returning false would result in infinite loop of calls.